# Apache AGE - create a new vertex label and load vertices from a CSV file into an existing graph

Tags: apache-age

I have a graph called 'employees' that contains data on employees, including their names, addresses, and email addresses. I need to update this graph by adding new nodes or vertices that contain additional information, such as phone numbers and departments from a csv file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add more nodes through a CSV file to an already existing graph, you can use the 'load_labels_from_file' function.

Assuming that there's already a graph called 'employees' with some nodes in it, we can use employees.csv to add further nodes. Do take note of the format of the CSV file first.

Taken from the official AGE docs:

> A CSV file for nodes shall be formatted as following;
>
> id: It shall be the first column of the file and all values shall be a
> positive integer. This is an optional field when id_field_exists is
> false. However, it should be present when id_field_exists is not set
> to false.
>
> Properties: All other columns contains the properties for the nodes.
> Header row shall contain the name of property

If the label for each node inside the 'employees' graph is called 'emp', then the CSV data can be loaded through:

```
SELECT load_labels_from_file('employees','emp','/path/to/employees.csv');
```

If you want to use a different label that does not already exist in your graph, you'll have to create it first before loading the CSV.

```
SELECT create_vlabel('employees','new_label');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new label for vertices (in case you do not have it already) using `SELECT create_vlabel('graph_name','vertex_name');`.
You can use `load_labels_from_file` function to load vertices from csv file.

```
SELECT load_labels_from_file('graph_name', 'vertex_name',
'path_to_csv_file');
```

You can then see the vertices using

```
SELECT * FROM graph_name."vertex_name";
```